# How to fix 'Cannot open include file 'boost/config.hpp': No such file or directory (Include Dirs covers: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0)

Tags: c++, boost

I am using MS VS 2017 Community, want to run Quantlib and Boost, put `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0` into "Include Directories" and `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0\libs` into "Library Directories". Building starts with some compilations, but then I get

```
Error C1083 "Cannot open include file: boost/config.hpp: No such file or directory."
```

I could jump to the error, it is in file 
`qldefines.hpp`, row

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
```

I tried additional pathes but didn't help. When I copy the file `config.hpp` to `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0` and change `#include <boost/config.hpp>` into `#include <config.hpp>` it works but obviously I would not like to change all the codings.

I would expect a compilation as the path to the include file is provided, but the error pops up as potentially the brackets < > could not be resolved.

Comment: How did you end up with boost in `Program Files`? You should download boost normally.

Comment: I put it under Documents but get the same result.

Comment: Where did you get boost from? Normal boost distribution from official site does have `boost/config.hpp` header.

Comment: *From* what directory did you copy `config.hpp`?

Comment: This means your include path you added for boost was wrong.

Comment: Does this folder: `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0` have a `boost` subfolder? The compiler is looking in `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0` for `boost\config.hpp` and not finding it.

Comment: Yes C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0 has a subfolder boost and there the file config.hpp is located. The error pops up when compiling qldefines.hpp in the line with the statement #include <boost/config.hpp>. I thought the include path is fine for finding C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0\boost\config.hpp but obviously it is not. I additionally put the path C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0\boost, but this also doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you did not set Additional Include Directories in *each and every project* in QuantLib, which has many projects. You can use the Property Manager (View -> Other Windows -> Property Manager) to add the correct Boost include path to all of the projects at once. Benjamin Whiteside has a very detailed blog post on [Building Quantlib in VS2017](https://benjaminwhiteside.com/2018/12/02/building-quantlib-in-vs2017/) which you may find helpful.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue and found a solution that might help you.
In addition to QuantLib and TestSuite, you need to configure the additional includes and library paths in all the projects within the examples folder.